# Linker error after upgrading to Xcode 4.6: armv7, ZBarSDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So i upgraded to Xcode 4.6 but i'm having problems. I can build and run program with no problem but when i try to create archive i get that error:

```
 Ld /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZM-dezzadmbbhmnbdehrgfgxsvipnzu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ZM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ZM.build/Release-iphoneos/ZM.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/ZM normal armv7s
cd /Users/me/Desktop/zav-mb-iphone-test
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -L/Users/mitjaresek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZM-dezzadmbbhmnbdehrgfgxsvipnzu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ZM/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/mitjaresek/Desktop/zav-mb-iphone-test/ZBarSDK -F/Users/mitjaresek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZM-dezzadmbbhmnbdehrgfgxsvipnzu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ZM/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/mitjaresek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZM-dezzadmbbhmnbdehrgfgxsvipnzu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ZM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ZM.build/Release-iphoneos/ZM.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/ZM.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -liconv -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MessageUI -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lzbar -o /Users/mitjaresek/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZM-dezzadmbbhmnbdehrgfgxsvipnzu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ZM/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ZM.build/Release-iphoneos/ZM.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/ZM

ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/me/iphone-test/ZBarSDK/libzbar.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So how do i fix it?

I'm getting really annoyed by that upgrade...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue. For some bizarre reason, removing the entries for ArmV6 & 7, then re-entering them seemed to solve it:

[image]

Comment: Indeed. I'm glad you got it fixed. =)

Comment: @Robert not working for me i m using xcode  4.6 and device is iphone5