# linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, linker-errors, xcode5

In my app, I am getting the following  **Linker Error**.

Previously, I made the project in `XCODE 4.6` & **Works perfectly in it**

`But When I try to run the project in XCODE 5, I am facing following error`

[image]

I search a lot but could not able to find any good solution.

My external Framwork are twitter and urabanAirship
so i have done setting in my project target>build settings> search paths >Header search path.
Is that any wrong with this setting.
 I also applied the same setting in Library Search path but no luck.
[image]

Help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use cocoapods ?

Comment: @adriencog,Thanks for your reply! No I am not using cocoapods.

Comment: @adriencog can you explain what cocoapods has to do with this?

Comment: I remember I had this error when I migrated my project to xcode 5. I had to update cocoapods, that supports last xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

I think your architecture is "armv7, armv7s". change to "armv7" only in Build Settings,

[image]

Comment: what error? same linker error is coming? Are you change "Yes" for Build Active architecture only. and also check your compiler is LLVM

Comment: ya, same error coming .i have done both change armv7 and "YES".

Comment: i am also facing this error. it is solved by this way. and try to change deployment target also, check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157977/ld-symbol-dyld-stub-binding-helper-not-found-normally-in-crt1-o-dylib1-o-bundl/19158212#19158212

Comment: You could try deleting 'armv7' then reinserting it, similar to that described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892429/linker-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-6-armv7-zbarsdk/14892644#14892644